# Adding Extra Field on Products Image Gallery

Tags: product-images

How can I add a text area onto the Image Gallery Attribute on Products. Right now it has Image,Label,Sort Order, Base Image, Small Image, Thumbnail, Exclude and Remove. I need to add a text area for a short description for the image. Any help will be much appreciated.